# ubuntu 14.04 server memory problems

Tags: 14.04, server, performance, ram

I'm getting this weird memory problem that causes massive slow down on any programs but doesnt want to go away till reboot.

so when i do htop the memory usage shows half my ram is used but if i do free -m it shows this

```
main@vps25801:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096       4014         81         69          0       1916
-/+ buffers/cache:       2097       1998
Swap:          128        123          4
```

top shows this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvufdock3c14jwr/Screenshot%202015-01-16%2006.53.42.png?dl=0

It says i have like 80 mb free. and the buffer/cache is what im guessing htop is reading.

Can someone tell me why this is going on.

If you need more information tell me and ill post it.

Comment: According to your screenshot (next time copying the terminal content is better than screenshots!) your RAM is eaten up 75% by java and 10% by php. What applications have you running in the java vm or that use php?
Maybe a java app you once started did not properly terminate all its threads?

Comment: I'm running minecraft and php idk im not using php. Minecraft only has allocated 2.5 gb ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htop` does it right, and reads free/used memory the same way as the line +/- buffers/cache shows in `free -m` output.
Check this thread about the details: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/why-do-free-and-or-top-show-different-memory-usage-than-the-new-relic-ui/273

Comment: but why is it that my programs get so sluggish when the memory usage in top is showing almost full and htop shows like 2.5 gb ram used?

Comment: what bothers me most is that almost all of your swap space ("virtual memory") is used up:123 of 128 MB is used...although you still have 1998MB RAM free...

Comment: Ya i know. That's idicating to me something isn't right. I have tryed reinstalling it but made it worse

Comment: I only see 30-80 mb of free mem. And swap should generally be about as big as ram, yours is very small. To configure how Ubuntu balances RAM and swap you have to set "swappines" in a config file - google is your friend. And minecraft might in reality use some more memory, as the java vm also needs resources.

Comment: he definitely has 1998MB of RAM usable by the kernel...
-/+ buffers/cache:       2097       1998

Comment: just kinda confused because i thought if i was running a vps on OpenVZ i didnt have any control over swap?

Comment: btw based on your screenshot above it is your CPU which is used 75% by "java" and 10% by "php". I guess this vps is simply cannot bear this load...CPU Load is around 3, and in case you have only one CPU assigned in the VM so the load is exactly triple for it.

Comment: I have 3 cores in this vps